# ¿Cómo mostrar barra de progreso en la subida de un archivo en un Post en HttpClient C#?

Tags: c#, post, http, xamarin.forms, progressbar

he durado horas intentando mostrar barra de progreso en la subia de archivos en un servidor mediante POST.

Uso la plataforma de Xamarin Forms, y necesito mostrar un progreso en porcentaje de la subida del archivo, he visto en varios post y no he logrado conseguir esto, este seria mi Código:

**Este el metodo que uso para hacer Post**

```
public static async Task<Response> PostProof(string filePath, string Request, string[] Parameters = null)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {


                    using (var content =
                        new MultipartFormDataContent())
                    {

                        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                        var fileByte = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

                        content.Add(new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(fileByte)), "file_data", fileName);

                        HttpResponseMessage result;
                        using (Acr.UserDialogs.IProgressDialog progress =
                            (Acr.UserDialogs.UserDialogs.Instance.Progress("Subiendo archivo...", null, null, true, Acr.UserDialogs.MaskType.Black)))
                        {
                            result = await client.PostAsync(Request, 
                                new ProgressableStreamContent(
                                 content,
                                 (sent, total) =>
                                 {
                                    var percentDouble = sent/total*100;
                                    progress.PercentComplete = Convert.ToInt32(percentDouble);
                                 }));
                        }

                        if (!result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        {
                            return new Response
                            {
                                IsSucces = false,
                                Message = "Hubo un error al crear, intentelo de nuevo...",
                            };
                        }

                        string data = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                        return new Response
                        {
                            IsSucces = true,
                            Message = "Ok",
                        };

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return new Response
                {
                    IsSucces = false,
                    Message = e.Message,
                }; ;
            }
        }
```

**Y Esta es la clase que me ayuda a obtener el progreso**

```
internal class ProgressableStreamContent : HttpContent
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Lets keep buffer of 20kb
        /// </summary>
        private const int defaultBufferSize = 4096;

        private HttpContent content;
        private int bufferSize;
        private Action<long, long> progress;


        public ProgressableStreamContent(HttpContent content, Action<long, long> progress) : this(content, defaultBufferSize, progress) { }

        public ProgressableStreamContent(HttpContent content, int bufferSize, Action<long, long> progress)
        {
            if (content == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("content");
            }
            if (bufferSize <= 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("bufferSize");
            }

            this.content = content;
            this.bufferSize = bufferSize;
            this.progress = progress;

            foreach (var h in content.Headers)
            {
                this.Headers.Add(h.Key, h.Value);
            }
        }

        protected override Task SerializeToStreamAsync(Stream stream, System.Net.TransportContext context)
        {


            return Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                var buffer = new Byte[this.bufferSize];
                long size;
                TryComputeLength(out size);
                var uploaded = 0;

                using (var sinput = await content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        var length = sinput.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        if (length <= 0) break;

                        //downloader.Uploaded = uploaded += length;
                        uploaded += length;
                        progress?.Invoke(uploaded, size);

                        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Bytes sent {uploaded} of {size}");

                        stream.Write(buffer, 0, length);
                        //stream.Flush();
                    }
                }
                stream.Flush();
            });
        }

        protected override bool TryComputeLength(out long length)
        {
            length = content.Headers.ContentLength.GetValueOrDefault();
            return true;
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                content.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

    }
```

Al parecer si funciona, el problema es que aparece el DialogProgress, luego enseguida carga al 100%, y luego se demora me imagino es cuando en verdad realiza la subida del archivo y no muestra en tiempo real ese progreso.

**Mi pregunta es ¿como hago para que en verdad muestre el progreso del archivo cuando es subido, muchas gracias por su atenció?**